# How to read child class exception message by catching with Exception in java

Tags: java, exception

```
class Student {

   public static Student getStudent(int id) throws StudentNotFoundException {
      throw new StudentNotFoundException("Student not found");

   }

   public static void main(String... args){
     
        try{
          Student student = getStudent(1);
        }catch(Exception e){
           //want to print the exception message passed from getUser() method i.e. Student not found
        }

  }
}
```

How to print the exception thrown by getStudent method by catching it using Exception.?

Comment: This code will fail. I leave it to the OP to identify where and why it will fail.

Comment: Your code will not even compile.

Comment: Take a look at the function definition. Its missing `(int id)` and to print the message, `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Comment: Have you read the official JavaDoc for Exception?

Answer (score 1):

```
e.printStackTrace();                  // print to error message and stack trace to standard error
System.out.println(e.getMessage());   // print only the message to standard output
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the exception message, use the eponymous, `e.getMessage()` method.